# Angular 5. ng build --prod works. Deployed application fails

Tags: angular, npm

all worked fine until last npm update

Look at http://projects.mcrit.com/dist/

I'm using:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.56
Node: 8.9.4
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

@angular/cdk: 5.1.0
@angular/cli: 1.6.5
@angular/material: 5.1.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.41
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.28
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.51
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.5
@schematics/angular: 0.1.16
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

I can compile application using ng build -prod but deployed application on apache server fails.

Chrome message is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
Firefox message is: SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control

No -prod build works fine on server

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Please provide sample of the component code where the error is rising

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The error is in the main.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.js file

Comment: check with ng serve --prod --source-map

Comment: compiled successfully.

But localhost:4200 fails as complied and deployed version.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<base href="./">`  as `<base href="/">` or `<base href="/dist/">` in index.html

Comment: <base href="/"> can't find js... includes
<base href="/dist/"> same error as with ./